# SSIS Lookup transformation used inside for-each loop gets stuck

Tags: ssis, lookup, foreach-loop-container

I have a SSIS package which load currencies data from source file to sql server table.Using foreach ADO enumerator using ADO object source variable to get the list of currencies from source file and inside foreach loop using lookup transformation to have currencies lookup and load non matched data into db table. Package executes the first currency iteration data into db table but for second currency it gets stuck. when checked for any blocking i saw Schema stability lock causing the issue. Not sure how can i fix this.

Things that i tried.

1. Tried changing the option from full cache to partial cache and no cache but same.
2. Tried using Stored procedure to load the lookup data instead of direct table in lookup transformation but same.
3. Checked for the blank or null values in the list of currencies loaded inside ADO enumerator object variable, Where i found one blank value . Removed it and ran the package but still getting stuck.
4. I found that the for each loop stucks only when there is no matched data PRESENT to load . If NO records are present to load, then the package runs fine.

Expecting that the foreach loop should pick each currency data one by one and load records into db table when there is no match found in lookup.

Comment: Without the package it is hard to visualize but if you are reading from a file in ach loop the file could be getting locked and not released.  I would suggest you import the currencies file into a stage/temp table BEFORE the loops.  Then inside the loop instead of reading a file each time you could use the temp/stage table for the loopk up.  Or depending on what you are doing you could import both files into the DB and then do a bulk process on both stage/temp tables.

Comment: What does "stuck" mean?

Comment: Hi Brad Thanks for your answer, Yes this approch i tried but dint work After adding stage table it is still stuck into infinite loop

Comment: Hi 
billinkc
Stuck meaning the for each loop keeps on executing and does not move ahead

Comment: Thanks . In my case I found that while loading the package it use to give error mesg that few packages were not loaded properly where I was clicking ok and moving ahead to run package. In this case only it was getting stuck. So I tried opening the solution on local system instead opening it on dev server and found no error on local system. Running the package here dint stuck so synced the working package to git and the pulled the latest package on dev server and tried executing on dev which worked for me.